# how to use yield to return the collection of Item in parallel block or Task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, system.reactive

I looking for help on how to make use of yield keyword to return IEnumberable in parallel blocks or Task block. Below is the pseudo code

```
public IEnumerable<List<T>> ReadFile( )
{
    foreach (string filepath in lstOfFiles)
    {
        var stream = new FileStream(filepath , FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        foreach (var item in ReadStream(stream))
            yield return item; //where item is of type List<string>
    }
}
```

I want to convert above code to parallel block like below

```
lstOfFiles.AsParallel()
          .ForAll(filepath =>
{
    var stream = new FileStream(filepath , FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    foreach (var item in ReadStream(Stream))
        yield return item;
});
```

but compiler throws error that Yield cannot be used in Parallel blocks or anonymous delegate. I tried with Task block also, yield is not allowed in task anonymous delegate

Any one suggest me simple and best way to have yield to return collection of data in parallel blocks or task.

I read that RX 2.0 or TPL are good to use in the above scenario. I have a doubt whether to make use of RX or TPL library for asynchronous return of yield of values. Can any one suggest me which is better either Rx or TPL.

If i use of Rx, is it necessary to create subscribe and convert parallel block AsObservable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to use `SelectMany`. You can't use `yield` in an anonymous method, but you can break this out into a new method, like so:

```
IEnumerable<Item> items = lstOfFiles.AsParallel()
    .SelectMany(( filepath ) => ReadItems(filepath));

IEnumerable<Item> ReadItems(string filePath)
{
    using(var Stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        foreach (var item in ReadStream(Stream))
            yield return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nelson, thnx for providing the help, looks like compileris throwing error has type cannot be inferred frm the usage..try specifying argument explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

To use Rx, you'll have to use `IObservable<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>`.

```
public IObservable<T> ReadFiles()
{
  return from filepath in lstOfFiles.ToObservable()
         from item in Observable.Using(() => File.OpenRead(filepath), ReadStream)
         select item;
}
```

Each time that you call `Subscribe` on the observable returned by `ReadFiles`, it will iterate over all of the strings in `lstOfFiles` and, in parallel*, read each file stream.

Sequentially, the query opens each file stream and passes it to `ReadStream`, which is responsible for generating the asynchronous sequence of items for a given stream.

The `ReadFiles` query, which uses the `SelectMany` operator written in query comprehension syntax, merges each "item" that is generated by all `ReadStream` observables into a single observable sequence, respecting the asynchrony of the source.

You should strongly consider writing an [async iterator](http://davesexton.com/blog/post/Async-Iterators.aspx) for your `ReadStream` method as I've shown here; otherwise, if you must return `IEnumerable<T>`, then you'll have to convert it by applying the `ToObservable(scheduler)` operator with a concurrency-introducing scheduler, which may be less efficient.

```
public IObservable<Item> ReadStream(Stream stream)
{
  return Observable.Create<Item>(async (observer, cancel) =>
  {
    // Here's one example of reading a stream with fixed item lengths.

    var buffer = new byte[itemLength]; // TODO: Define itemLength
    var remainder = itemLength;
    int read;

    do
    {
      read = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, itemLength - remainder, remainder, cancel)
                         .ConfigureAwait(false);

      remainder -= read;

      if (read == 0)
      {
        if (remainder < itemLength)
        {
          throw new InvalidOperationException("End of stream unexpected.");
        }
        else
        {
          break;
        }
      }
      else if (remainder == 0)
      {
        observer.OnNext(ReadItem(buffer));  // TODO: Define ReadItem

        remainder = itemLength;
      }
    }
    while (true);
  });
}
```

* Rx does not introduce any concurrency here. Parallelization is simply a result of the asynchronous nature of the underlying API, so it's very efficient. Reading from a file stream asynchronously may cause Windows to use an I/O completion port as an optimization, notifying on a pooled thread when each buffer becomes available. This ensure that Windows is entirely responsible for scheduling callbacks to your application, rather than the TPL or yourself.

Rx is free-threaded, so every notification to your observer may be on a different pooled thread; however, due to Rx's serialization contract (§4.2 [Rx Design Guidelines](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=205219)), you will not receive overlapping notifications in your observer when you call `Subscribe`, so there's no need to provide explicit synchronization, such as locking.

However, due to the parallelized nature of this query, you may observe alternating notifications with respect to each file, but never overlapping notifications.

If you'd rather receive all items for a given file at once, as you've hinted at in your question, then you can simply apply the `ToList` operator to the query and change the return type:

```
public IObservable<IList<T>> ReadFiles()
{
  return from filepath in lstOfFiles.ToObservable()
         from items in Observable.Using(() => File.OpenRead(filepath), ReadStream)
                                 .ToList()
         select items;
}
```

If you need to observe notifications with thread affinity (on a GUI thread, for instance), then you must marshal the notifications because they will be arriving on a pooled thread. Since this query does not introduce concurrency itself, the best way to achieve this is to apply the `ObserveOnDispatcher` operator (WPF, Store Apps, Phone, Silverlight) or the `ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext)` overload (WinForms, ASP.NET, etc.). Just don't forget to add a reference to the appropriate platform-specific NuGet package; e.g., Rx-Wpf, Rx-WinForms, Rx-WindowsStore, etc.

You may be tempted to convert the observable back into an `IEnumerable<T>` instead of calling `Subscribe`. Do not do this. In most cases it's unnecessary, it can be inefficient and in the worst case it could potentially cause dead locks. Once you enter the world of asynchrony, you should try to stay in it. This is not just true for Rx but also for `async/await`.

Comment: Hey Dave, i'm new Rx, but how can we have subscribe instead of tolist() which might cause deadlock as per ur statement i would like to know how subscribe when mutliple from clause are available

Comment: The `ToList` operator that I've used in my example is defined in the `System.Reactive.Linq.Observable` class and works on `IObservable<T>`, not `IEnumerable<T>`. The return value is `IObservable<IList<T>>`, so it's safe. Also you shouldn't call `Subscribe` in the middle of a query. Only call it at the very end.

Comment: Thnx Dave, i found tolist from LINQ.Observable after posting my comment,i tested it out it not blocking. I added subscribing like below which is works perfectly ReadFiles(childFiles).ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default).Subscribe(( result ) => { Console.WriteLine(result.Count);Console.WriteLine("Subscribe thread ID:{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);}); I have one more question, when i execute above code, i always see all the "ReadStream" methods runs in one thread and subscriber in another thread, Is it possible to run all files (says 4 files) in different threads and single subscribe thread

Comment: Well, you're using ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default), which is pointless. The "Default" scheduler actually introduces concurrency, but your notifications are already on pooled threads. "Default" is poorly named and should really never be used. Actually, you almost never have to use the ObserveOn operator at all; however, ObserveOnDispatcher() is often useful though, in GUI apps. I'd recommend that you ignore which threads are in use. Unless your app is thread-affine, it doesn't matter at all.

Comment: As for your new question, the query runs all of the callbacks in parallel based on Windows' scheduling, assuming that you're using my suggestion and relying on the async file APIs. Since the callbacks are on pooled threads, it's perfectly reasonable for the same pooled thread to be used repeatedly for successive operations. Whether or not you can get actual parallel operations depends on the number of processors in your computer and other factors. Just leave it up to Windows to decide.

Comment: suuper dave. ur awesome. thnx for clarifying