# composing commands to chain with parallel execution

Tags: c#, system.reactive, command-pattern, chain-of-responsibility

I am looking for a pattern(s) suitable for this scenario.

I need process files from HDD in this way.

1. Load file
2. Analyze file
3. Validate file based on analyze result
4. Import file to app based on validation result

This process can be change in future.

My idea is create command for each file action (Command pattern).

- LoadFileCommand : IFileCommand
- AnalyzeFileCommand : IFileCommand
- ValidateFileCommand : IFileCommand
- ImportFileCommand: IFileCommand

Code:

```
public interface IFileCommand
{
  FileCommandResult Execute();
  void Abort();
}
public class FileCommandResult
{ 
  FileInfo File{get;}
  bool Sucesss{get;}
  string Error{get;}
}
```

I need create process with commands (chain with commands).

I try use for this purpose Chain of resposibility pattern but maybe exist better pattern or design.

If it is possible I would like use Rx and also parallel execution will be nice.

I would like achieve this:

```
var data = new List<FileInfo>();

var process = new List<IFileCommand>{new LoadFileCommand(), new AnalyzeFileCommand(), new ValidateFileCommand(), new ImportFileCommand()};

var processor = new FileProcessor();

IEnumerable<IFileCommandResult> results = processor.Execute(process, data);
```

Any ideas.

Comment: Is this for school? Just curious. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27671917/how-to-use-yield-to-return-the-collection-of-item-in-parallel-block-or-task

Comment: @DaveSexton: It isn’t school problem. Your answer is about read files via Stream my main problem is how to chain commands and create process.

Comment: I'm just wondering why you need commands at all.

Comment: Essentially, it seems like all you need is to chain together one `SelectMany` for each "command".

Comment: @DaveSexton: IMHO with SelectMany I can not pass result from LoadFileCommand to AnalyzeFileCommand, from AnalyziFileCommand to ValidateFileCommand etc but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: No, that's exactly the point of `SelectMany`. It's the asynchronous sequential composition operator in Rx. It's like for each x in xs, for each y in ys, select (x,y). Notice that `x` and `y` are both in scope in `select`.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use Rx for this?  If you want to represent your operations as a sequence of commands, then just use LINQ to apply the command chain.  If you want them to run in parallel, then just use PLINQ, TPL, or Parallel.ForEach.  You might also take a look at [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Here's 3 ways to solve your problem.  Note I did not implement error handling or mess with your `Abort` method and I took some liberties with your `Execute` method since what you had was unusable.  I now assume `Execute` has this signature: `FileInfo Execute(FileInfo)` and that it throws an exception if it fails.

```
IEnumerable<FileInfo> data = ...;
IEnumerable<IFileCommand> process = ...;

// PLINQ
var results = data
    .AsParallel()
    .Select(dataItem => process.Aggregate(dataItem, (d, p) => p.Execute(d)))
    .ForAll(dataItem => import(dataItem));


// Parallel.Foreach
Parallel.Foreach(data, dataItem => import(process.Aggregate(dataItem, (d, p) => p.Execute(d))));

// TPL
var tasks = data
    .Select(dataItem => Task.Run(() => import(process.Aggregate(dataItem, (d, p) => p.Execute(d)))));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: Well loading from a file is an async operation. If you're going to use LINQ then why not Rx and keep it close to the metal? I'm just not sure what use the commands are, unless this isn't meant to be an automated process?

Comment: @DaveSexton yeah if the commands were modeled as async operations then maybe Rx would be useful. Or still just a bunch of TPL or Dataflow.  But with synchronous commands I can't see why it is worth converting to Rx. One useful aspect of the commands instead of straight Rx or TPL is that they are effectively data and the chain can be dynamically adjusted.